# Probability - Diagnostic Tests, expected cost per person

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that for a randomly selected person:

$P (D) = 0.02$, $P (R\mid D) = 1,$ $P (R\mid D') = 0.05$

So that the inexpensive test only gives false positive, and not false negative, results.

Suppose that this inexpensive test costs 10 dollars.

If a person tests positive then they are also given a more expensive test, costing 100 dollars, which correctly identifies all persons with the disease.

What is the expected cost per person if a population is tested for the disease using the inexpensive test followed, if necessary, by the expensive test?

Beginning with the question, I'm not sure which formula to plug in and use, any help will be appreciated thanks!!

*Edit*

Let $D = \{\text{person has the condition}\}$

Let $R = \{\text{the test result is positive}\}$

Comment: What exactly are the events D and R?

Comment: Sorry edited in!

Comment: I think you should edit the probability too, did you P(R/D') = 0.05

Comment: sorry edited as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(D) = .02$

$P(R/D) = 1$

$P(R/D') = .05$

$P(D') = 1-.02 = 0.98$

$P(R) = P(D)P(R/D) + P(D')P(R/D') = .02(1) + .98(.05) = .069$

Cost of inexpensive + follow up test, if tested positive $=10 + 0.069(100)$$

Expected cost $= 10+ 0.069*100 = 16.9 $$

Comment: Sorry but my answer in the book seems to be $16.90, do you think its wrong?

Comment: They are right, the everyone takes the inexpensive test to find if it is positive, so there is no probability there, but the $ 100 is spent only if it is positive.  They are correct it should be 10+ 0.069*100 = 16.9, I will edit it.

Comment: Alright i got it, thanks a lot man!